# Rails, Nested Resource, Update Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, form-for, nested-resources

I'm trying to have a simple button to update for each Comment through a submit form. Here is my View code:

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= form_for comment, url: article_comment_path(comment.article, comment), method: :patch do |f| %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :update_time, Time.now %>
        <%= f.submit "Confirm" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comments Controller Update Action Code:

```
def update
  @article = Article.friendly.find(params[:article_id])
  @comment = @user.comments.find(params[:id])

  if @comment.update(comment_params)
    redirect_to @comments
  else
    render article_comments_path(@article)
  end
end

private
        def comment_params
          params.require(:comment).permit(:date, :note)
        end
```

With the code above, I'm getting this error:

param is missing or the value is empty: comment
  - the error highlights the params.require line in the private declaration

Comment: Hi if my answer was useful, please consider select it as accepted answer, that's how the community works...

Comment: Hi, Im still waiting for you to mark my answer as accepted, I spent some time answering you... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is pretty simple, look at your form, you do not have any `:note` so when you try to require `:note` in your params hash then you get that error because there is not `:note` key in your params hash, for get around this you have two options:

1. Create another params method and use it conditionally:

   `private
   def comment_params
     params.require(:comment).permit(:date, :note)
   end
   def comment_params_minimal
     params.require(:comment).permit(:date)
   end`

and then use it conditionally in your `update` action:

```
def update
  @article = Article.friendly.find(params[:article_id])
  @comment = @user.comments.find(params[:id])
  if params[:comment][:note].present?
    use_this_params = comment_params
  else
    use_this_params = comment_params_minimal
  end
  if @comment.update(use_this_params)
    redirect_to @comments
  else
    render article_comments_path(@article)
  end
end
```

2. The other way is tu directly update your comment using `params` hash instead of whitelist them with `comment_params` so `if params[:comment][:note].present?` update in the normal fashion else, update only the `date` attribute directly: `params[:comment][:date]`

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

You are submitting to the article comment path, but your form is for article(like in your code  <%= form_for article) and not comment. Thus the params you should look for first is the article params[:article]. I think if you put a debugger like this

```
def update
  debugger #<<<<<<<<<
  @article = Article.friendly.find(params[:article_id])
  @comment = @user.comments.find(params[:id])

  if @comment.update(comment_params)
    redirect_to @comments
  else
    render article_comments_path(@article)
  end
end
```

You can then check the params that is submitting to your controller update action. And most likely you will find your comment params in your article params like

```
params[:article][:comment]
```

but I am just guessing here. With debugger and server log you can check exactly what param were submitted to your update action.